# raspberry pi bluetooth and lego mindstorm

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, lego-mindstorms

I am trying to get a lego mindstorm ev3 to communicate with a Raspberry Pi. I am able to get the mindstorm to send data to the Pi but the data is not human readable. My end goal is to be able to send some sensor information from the mindstorm to the Pi and have the Pi make a decision based on that data. The data I am currently recieving looks like this '\xof\x00\x01\x00\x81\x9e\x04abc\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'. This string came from the mindstorm sending the number 1 to the Pi.

Is there a way I can figure out what this data means so that I can use it to make decisions in python.

The way the two are connected was done by following the instructions here http://gipprojects.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/using-python-and-raspberry-pi-to-communicate-with-lego-mindstorms-ev3/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you linked give a good explanation of how to interpret the data. You should not be looking at is as a string (text), but rather as bytes. Each byte has a specific meaning depending on which command you are receiving.

For additional information check out the LEGO firmware documentation [Communications Overview](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen/communication.html). I am guessing the command you are dealing with is the WRITEMAILBOX [System Command](http://ev3.fantastic.computer/doxygen/systemcommands.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. The issue I am having is that while following the instructions I still end up with payload being equal to '\x00\x00\x00\x00' which according to the link you posted means "SUCCESS". I am wondering if there is a way of getting the actual number sent from the EV3 which originally was the number 1.

Comment: Actually I think it may have been an error with what I was expecting the mindstorm to output. I changed it to send text instead of numeric and had it send "TEST" now I am getting '\x10\x00\x01\x00\x81\x9e\x04abc\x00\x05\x00TEST\x00' which when I get down to the payload gives me "TEST". Thank you for the help.